# How to fill a cell with an image

Tags: css

Hi I am using 3px*10px gradient image to fill in a  I want to fill in the complete cell with this image and also I wanted to stretch the images automatically if the content of the cell increases..However I dont want it to repeat as the image is a gradient it looks ugly. Can someone please help.

the code snipet is as follows.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr><td>a<td rowspan="9" style="background-image:url('images/bg_menu_hov.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat; height:100%;">&nbsp<td>b</tr>
<tr><td>c<td>d</tr>
<tr><td>e<td>f</tr>
<tr><td>c<td>d</tr>
<tr><td>e<td>f</tr>
<tr><td>c<td>d</tr>
<tr><td>e<td>f</tr>
<tr><td>c<td>d</tr>
<tr><td>e<td>f</tr>
</table>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: saying cell, you mean a cell of a table or a div? (or anything else)

Comment: Stretching a gradient image that small will look ugly no matter what you do. It's going to get blocky/pixelized very quickly since you're starting with a microscopic image.

Comment: Thats fine if it gets pixelized..As I want to know the work around for this situation

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the image, you will need to set up your [background-repeat](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-repeat.asp) differently.

Stretching the image is probably not a good idea. Generally you should make your gradient wide or high enough to suit your design. It's a good idea to fade the gradient out to a same color as a background color you set.

Judging from your image size (3px*10px) I'm guessing you need to set background-repeat to 'repeat-x'.

Comment: Well thats will only tile the images..It will not stretch

Comment: Like I said, it's [not recommended and hacky](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm) and the usual workaround is to provide a image which is (in your scenario) high enough. CSS3 [will seem to support this](http://requiem4adream.wordpress.com/2006/09/29/css-stretch-background-image/).

Answer (score 0):

If as your code suggest, you're using an image that's 3px wide, but looks really ugly if it's tiled, it's not likely to look much better stretched.

If the gradient is purely vertical, consider narrowing the original image to be 1px wide. That way there'll be no noise from repeating it horizontally.

Comment: Ohn and then change no-repeat to repeat-x

Comment: Well that will tile the images not stretch the image

Comment: With a one pixel wide image, stretching and tiling achieve the same visual result. Tiling is easier to implement.

Comment: If it was me I would make the image one pixel wide, and higher than it would ever need to be, then use repeat-x to tile it horizontally. When it comes to loading a page quickly, the difference between a 1x60 image and a 1x600 isn't that important.